# Creating a shortcut for cmd from powershell with arguments - exception cannot save with 0 args

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

```
$WshShell = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut("C:\Users\$user\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\CheckLauncher.lnk")
$Shortcut.TargetPath = "cmd.exe"
$Shortcut.Arguments = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Packages\checkLauncher.bat"
```

Error

```
Exception calling "Save" with "0" argument(s): "Unable to save shortcut "C:\Use
rs\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\
CheckLauncher.lnk"."
At C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Packages\Setup.ps1:22 char:15
+ $Shortcut.Save <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation
```

I assure you that this path - C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Packages\checkLauncher.bat does exist.
Please do help to find out what is wrong with this.

Any help is awaited.. Thanks in advance

Comment: I have the administrative permissions. I was earlier creating shortcut for a ps scrip.. It was working fine. Now it isnt

Answer (score 3):

I can successfully create a shortcut using this approach however, have you defined `$user` somewhere else because that isn't defined by default. Perhaps you meant to use `$env:username`?  Alternatively you could use `$home` to get the `c:\users\<username>` part of the path.  And even better is to use this .NET method:

```
[Environment]::GetFolderPath([environment+specialfolder]::ApplicationData)
```

I think you also want to specify the arguments like so:

```
$Shortcut.Arguments = "/c C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Packages\checkLauncher.bat"
```

The following works fine for me:

```
$roaming = [environment]::GetFolderPath([environment+specialfolder]::ApplicationData)
$path = "$roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\UpdateBinDir.lnk"
$WshShell = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell
$shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut($path)
$shortcut.TargetPath = "cmd.exe"
$shortcut.Arguments = "/c C:\bin\updateBinDir.bat"
$shortcut.Save()
```

Comment: I have $user defined in the same script. $user=[Environment]::UserName  I have tried the /c in arguments too.. Stil it gives the same error

Comment: I don't think that is the issue because in the error the path has been resolved.. There is Administrator inplace of $user

Comment: I tried your code with only file name changes needed. Yet its giving the same error

Comment: If you are not running this code under the Administrator account, I doubt you have access to the bat file in the Administrator user dir.  Try moving the bat file to a location where you have access as you run this code and then try to create the shortcut with that path.